# How to run different threads concurrently in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust

Let's say I have two threads that have different intent (T1, T2). T1 is responsible for pushing messages into a queue and T2 is responsible for popping messages. How do I implement a way to run T1 and T2 together?

I tried looking at existing multithreaded implementations and examples in rust but most of them are about spawning multiple threads for the same job.

````
//using an Arc object of an ArrayQueue
let handle1 = thread::spawn( move || {
//clone arc object
//push
});

let handle2 = thread::spawn( move || {
//clone arc object
//pop
});```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think the threads are not running concurrently ?
For easily passing data between threads you can use the MPSC channel from the std library:

```
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    let sending_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 0..10 {
            println!("[{:?}] Sending: {}", std::thread::current().id(), i);
            sender.send(i).unwrap();
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        }
    });

    let receiving_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in receiver {
            println!("[{:?}] Received: {}", std::thread::current().id(), i);
        }
    });

    let _ = sending_thread.join();
    let _ = receiving_thread.join();
    println!("Done");
}
```